# Groovy:The field properties is declared multiple times

Tags: gradle, groovy

I want to get the value of a variable in my custom plugin class from `gradle.properties`. But I want to write and use it outside the `apply` method. So, I am writing like this :

```
class VCPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

   private Project project

   private Properties properties
   properties = new Properties()
   properties.load(project.rootProject.file('gradle.properties').newDataInputStream())
   def componentClass = properties.getProperty('componentClass')

   @Override
   void apply(Project project) {
      //applying distribution plugin
      this.project = project .....
   }
}
```

But this gives compile error:

> Groovy:The field properties is declared multiple times

Now, if I write it inside the apply method, then it works but I need to use `componentClass` variable outside the apply method so I need to write this outside. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code should do the job:

```
 class VCPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

  private Project project
  private Properties properties
  private String componentClass 

  @Override
  void apply(Project project) {
    this.project = project
    this.properties = new Properties()
    properties.load (project.rootProject.file('gradle.properties').newDataInputStream())
    this.componentClass = this.properties.getProperty('componentClass')
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that worked.I was thinking something different. This easy solution did not cross my mind. Any ways thanks for the help.